# Show labels on each sector to polar chart using angular js chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I'm using polar chart from `angular-chart.js` [library](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/). But my polar chart need to have routed label like below:

[image]

How I can achieve this requirement? Anyone has done it before?

Currently I'm just using the code from the source:

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("PolarAreaCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales", "Tele Sales", "Corporate Sales"];
  $scope.data = [300, 500, 100, 40, 120];
});
```

and my view:

```
<canvas id="polar-area" class="chart chart-polar-area"
  chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is another option using this extension:

> [Chart.PieceLabel.js](https://github.com/beaver71/Chart.PieceLabel.js)

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/39293jes/

or a snippet in SO:

```js
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("ChartCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
    
    $scope.data = [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40];
    var sum = $scope.data.reduce(function add(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
    
    $scope.options = {
      pieceLabel: {
        render: function (args) {
          return args.label + " " + Math.round(args.value*100/sum,2)+"%";
        },
        fontColor: '#000',
        position: 'outside',
        segment: true
      }
    };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.chartjs/latest/angular-chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/beaver71/Chart.PieceLabel.js/master/build/Chart.PieceLabel.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ChartCtrl">
  <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-polar-area"
         chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options">
  </canvas> 
</div>
```

Comment: No, sorry it's not possible, unless you change the code of the plugin

Answer (score 2):

Please check my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ankurpatel18/9b2msc95/) `Polar Chart` for your answer,

I had used extra extensions named

> [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/notes/extensions.html?h=chartjs-plugin-datalabels)

let me know if any more help require

Comment: Very nice... can the labels have the route?